# Select query too slow even though I'm using an index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here but I have a query running on a table with millions of rows.

The query is something like this:

```
select * 
  from    dbo.table with (index (index_1), nolock)
          where   col1 = 15464
                  and col2 not in ('X', 'U')
                  and col3 is null
                  and col4 = 'E'
```

Index looks like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_1] ON [dbo].[table] ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This select still takes over a minute to run. What am I missing?

Comment: Be careful with that NOLOCK hint. It may be ok in your situation but most people don't actually understand all the ramifications of that hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Try putting composite index on col1, col4. Rewrite where as col1 then col4, then the rest.

Comment: does the order of the where clause matter if I have the index order correct?

Comment: @Rj. Show us execution plan..

Comment: To my very limited knowledge, yes. Please try and provide feedback.

Comment: im working on a screenshot of the execution plan. one sec.

Comment: based on the execution plan, it told me to create the index that was mentioned in the first solution posted by Gordon Linoff ... but its telling me to include all the columns. im creating the index right now and im gonna run it again to see if that makes a difference. but based on the execution plan, it looks good. its doing an index seek (but also a key look up.. which is what im fixing right now). ill report back once i run it again

Comment: @Rj. Be careful if you include too much columns you'll actually copy a table. Can u show us picture.

Comment: the table has a ton of columns and the INCLUDE statement was going to include too many columns as well. i decided to keep the index without the INCLUDE statement. i can lose a minute on this query. thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Finally, does the order of where clause matter? Just to enhance my understanding.

Comment: the order of the where clause does not matter... it matters when you create the index. sql is smart enough to know which columns to look at first.

Comment: @Rj. What is selectivity of where clause? do you really need **ALL** column As result, coz with indexes col1 ... col4 QO has to use NL join to get all the columns in "*" , if any column if quite selective say col1 then you can use col1 index and push rest for residual predicate. for best answer provide schema and execution plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this query:

```
select * 
from table 
where col1 = 15464 and
      col2 not in ('X', 'U') and
      col3 is null and
      col4 = 'E';
```

The best index is `table(col1, col4, col3, col2)`.  The query should use the index automatically, without a hint.

When choosing an index based on a `where` clause, you should put the equality conditions in first -- followed by one column with an inequality.  For the purposes of indexing, `in` and `not in` are inequality conditions in general.

Also, if you mix data types, then sometimes indexes are not used.  So, this assumes that `col1` is numeric.

Comment: ahhh, I see why. it makes complete sense. sorry, still learning about indices :) .. i can accept your answer in 9 minutes ! thank you my friend.

Comment: hmmmm, well, it's still running over 1 min. do i need to "refresh" anything for SQL to realize the changes?

Comment: @Rj.  . . . If the query is in a stored procedure or somehow cached, you might need `option (recompile)`.  Otherwise, the issue might simply be that too many rows match.